# jQuery percentage value not working in IE7 & IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

Please help! I create a callback function for #somediv which is better to use percentage value to make it works properly in a responsive template, here is my code :

```
before: function(){
   jQuery('#somediv').hide().animate({bottom:'100%'});
}
after: function(){
   jQuery('#somediv').show().animate({bottom:0});
}
```

Unfortunately the code above only works in IE9 and it's working great if I use :

```
before: function(){
   jQuery('#somediv').hide().animate({bottom:400});
}
after: function(){
   jQuery('#somediv').show().animate({bottom:0});
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: why are you hiding and then animating?

Comment: That's for hide the movement of element from top to bottom.. someone will only seen the movement from bottom to top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
before: function(){
   // no need for hidden animations just set the css
   // you cannot animate percents in jQuery as not all browsers will support it
   // using offset parent you can find use the real px height instead of a 100%
   jQuery('#somediv').hide().css({bottom: jQuery('#somediv').offsetParent().height() });
}
after: function(){
   jQuery('#somediv').show().animate({bottom:0});
}
```

Comment: Yay! That was great.. many thanks for your help! but wait maybe it embarrassing to ask, I really dumb with coding.. how to convert it to negative value e.g -100% ?

Comment: just like in maths, multiply by -1